# Implementing a sticky section in the middle of the activity in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview, sticky

I'm now facing quite interesting problem in develpoing android app.

So, I have 3 sections, and the order is following.

[VIEW_ON_TOP]

[TO_BE_STICKED]

[SCROLLVIEW]

Of course, scroll view has many children views, anyway it might not seem to be the problem.
What I'm trying to do is that when I scroll the [VIEW_ON_TOP] until the top of the [TO_BE_STICKED] is on the top of the screen, the [TO_BE_STICKED] section should be sticked on the top literally, then I have to move on the focus on [SCROLLVIEW] for scrolling, which means that there are exactly two sections for scrolling.

Thus, what I'm thinking is that let these 3 sections be included in the one listview, so each section is one of the listitems, then it would be nothing but the problem for 2 listitems and one sticky header problem of listview. How do you think? Is it resonable idea? Or any other suggestions, or comments?

Please note that [VIEW_ON_TOP] and [SCROLLVIEW] is independent xml file, so it is needed to make these into object for listviewitem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple library on GitHub.

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

the procedure is following.

```
<com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sticky_scroll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5">
        <include
            layout="ON_TOP"
        />
        <View
            THIS IS FOR SEPARATE LINE
        />
        <include
            layout="ON_BOTTOM"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView>
```